# Generic logging class for tracing the function calls

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

// Generic class for tracing the function call
class functionlogging {
private:
    string name;
    string in{ ">>" };
    string out{ "<<" };
public:
    functionlogging(string x) :name(x) {
        cout << in << name << endl;
    }
    ~functionlogging(){
        cout << out << name << endl;
    }
};

//uses
void generic_function() {
    functionlogging logger{ __func__ };
    int a = 10;
    int b = 100;
    a += b;
}


int main() {
    generic_function();
}
```

Many times, we do need to log when function call starts and ends for better understanding.  With modern C++ concepts like `__funct__/RAII`, I wrote the small class which can be used to achieve trace. With this I was able to achieve this for above `"generic_function()"`.

## Output

```
>>generic_function
<<generic_function
```

I wanted others opinion about the `functionlogging` class and how to make it in such a way that user of this class would have to do the minimal work/code changes in his/her code base.

At present user of this class needs to create a object of this class and pass the `__func__` information. Is it acceptable or in a way can it be embed inside something by which user of the class almost do not require to do anything?.

Comment: You could use some preprocessor `#define` like with `assert`, if you like that more.

Comment: I can't find a meaning for your class, sorry. A debugger just works better.

Comment: @black. That is neither true nor a useful statement. In a data driven program the call history will not be obvious and thus logging is needed to trace where the code has been before a crash point (a lot of that stack information may no longer be available in the core file). Also the comment does not help in any way review the code.

Comment: @LokiAstari I'm looking for explainations which *do* help for a code review.
Also, your example is questionably related.

Comment: If you don't want to post a new question to get further feedback, you can always post your updated code as an answer to help future readers.  That's #3 in Jamal's link, and it seems to fit your stated goal best.

Comment: You should look into lttng tool provided by linux.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Stop doing this:

```
using namespace std;
```

see: [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/14065)

These two are not unique to the class.

```
string in{ ">>" };
string out{ "<<" };
```

May as well make them `static`. Also they re never modified so make them `const`.

No need to force a flush with `std::endl`

```
    cout << in << name << endl;
```

Prefer `"\n"` when you don't need a flush (also cerr or clog may be better choices of output stream).

That seems like an overly verbose and error prone way of use.

```
void generic_function() {
    functionlogging logger{ __func__ };
```

You have to use up a variable and remember `__func__`. Can't we get a macro in here to do all the for you? I actually need to look up to see if **func** is a standard macro.

Just checked the standard:

```
8.4.1 In general
Paragrah 8:
The function-local predefined variable __func__ is defined as if a definition of the form  

static const char __func__[] = "function-name ";
```

So I would define the macros:

```
#define LOG_ENTRY_EXIT_FOR(x)       functionlogging  SomeLongNameThatIsNotLikelyToBeUsedInTheFunctionlogger(x)
#define LOG_ENTRY_EXIT              LOG_ENTRY_EXIT_FOR(__func__)
```

Then usage is simply:

```
void generic_function() {
    LOG_ENTRY_EXIT;

    int a = 10;
    int b = 100;
    a += b;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The below is updated code after incorporating the suggestion in this post. This is just for easy reference for future reader.

```
  #include<iostream>
  #include<string>

    // Generic class for tracing the function call
    class functionlogging {
    private:
        std::string name;
        static std::string in;
        static std::string out;
    public:
        functionlogging(std::string x) :name(x) {
            std::cout << in << name <<"\n";
        }
        ~functionlogging(){
            std::cout << out << name <<"\n";
        }
    };

std::string functionlogging::in{ ">>" };
std::string functionlogging::out{ "<<" };


//Define MACRO for easy use for end user.
#define LOG_ENTRY_EXIT_FOR(x)       functionlogging  SomeLongNameThatIsNotLikelyToBeUsedInTheFunctionlogger(x)
#define LOG_ENTRY_EXIT              LOG_ENTRY_EXIT_FOR(__func__)


    //uses
    void generic_function() {
        LOG_ENTRY_EXIT;
        int a = 10;
        int b = 100;
        a += b;
    }


    int main() {
        generic_function();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a minor addition. Storing (and passing) the function name in a `const char*` will eliminate the costly (dynamic memory allocation) construction of a string.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds great. I would recommend a little improvement to [Loki Astari's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/66420/49350).

By changing the way you define LOG_ENTRY_EXIT,

```
#if defined(DEBUG)
#define LOG_ENTRY_EXIT   LOG_ENTRY_EXIT_FOR(__func__)
#else
#define LOG_ENTRY_EXIT
#endif
```

One will be able to compile it in or out for say release build if needed.

We use this type of tracing quite a lot in game development code.

Comment: If you're posting a comment to someone else's answer, but find it noteworthy enough to post as an answer, be sure to point out what answer you're referencing to.

Comment: I've edited your answer as an example; like this it's clearer where your contribution is coming from. When you get more reputation (50+), you'll be able to comment on other people's posts, after which you may want to write answers like this as comments instead.